# How to Create Border In Css Iike

Tags: html, css

here is image .
i want border like this.

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code on what you have already tried?

Comment: `:before` & `:after`

Comment: <h2 class="heading heading2"><img src="static1.png" width="150px" >

Comment: h2.heading
        {
            font-size:9pt;
            color:#000;
            font-weight:normal;
            padding:11mm 0mm 0mm 12mm;
        }
        h2.heading2
        {
         border: 1px solid;
      border-right-color: #ff0000;
      border-top-color: #ff0000; 
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```css
#mainDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  position: relative;
  background: grey;
}

.bottom-left-corner {
  margin: -5px;
  border-left: 1px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 25%;
  left: 0;
}

.top-right-corner {
  margin: -5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaaafa;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaaafa;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 0;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div class="bottom-left-corner"></div>
  <div class="top-right-corner"></div>
</div>
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWrzPX

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png">
  <span class="blue"></span>
  <span class="red"></span>
</div>

.image{position:relative;width:200px;height:200px}
.red{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;margin-right:0px;width:50%;height:50%;background:red;}
.blue{position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;width:50%;height:50%;background:blue}
img{background:#fff;position:absolute;z-index:100;padding:0px;margin:1px;width:198px;height:198px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.seowordpress.pl/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/images/default-user-image.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.example {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.example:after {
  position:absolute;
  width: 120px; 
  height: 120px;
  border: solid orange;
  content: ' ';
}

.example>:first-child:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px; 
  height: 120px;
  border: solid lightblue;
  content: ' ';
}

.example:after {
  right:0;
  top:0;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.example>:first-child:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xcanndy/t1wa825f/

Comment: please past it at jsfiddle, is better! and your answer looks better too